bash string replace has 'bad substitution' error
I am attempting to create a folder structure to test a backup script.
The folders are date based, and will have a modification time of the date of the folders name.
to do this i am creating a list of dates and iterating them, creating the directory and setting the modification time to the date.
#!/bin/bash
dates="2024-01-01 2024-01-02" # + many more.

for d in $dates ; do
    mkdir "/mnt/2024/Backups/${d}" 2>/dev/null
    t="${d//-/}0000"
    touch -a -m -t "${t}" "/mnt/2024/Backups/${d}"
done

if i run this script i get:
go.sh: 6: Bad substitution (which in my script is the line t="${d//-/}0000")
What is confusing is if i do testing on bash (ubuntu)
$ d=2024-01-01
$ t=${d//-/}
$ echo $t
20240101

it behaves as expected.
can anyone explain what is going on, or, how to fix it?

FWIW this t="$(echo $d | sed -r 's/-//g')0000" fixes the issue, but doesn't explain the reason for the error i am getting - so i have an answer - just don't know why the previous code was broken.

are you certain it's #!/bin/bash in the non working script?

@Jasen - that was it - if i run bash go.sh the script works. bash is at /usr/bin/bash on ubuntu - recently been working on RHEL - so i got confused thanks.

if you have resolved the issue, please provide the answers to your question, otherwise the reminder will persist until the end of the universe.

Reproducible:
$ cat file.sh
d=1234-5678
echo "${d//-/}"

$ bash file.sh
12345678

$ sh file.sh
file.sh: 2: Bad substitution

Resolution: run bash scripts with bash.
